# Xcode/iOS: does Maps need to be switched on in Capabilities?

Tags: ios, xcode, mapkit

I have integrated `MapKit` in my iOS app, and it works fine without switching **Maps** on in *xCode*/*target*/*Capabilities*.

So, does **Maps** need to be switched on in *Capabilities* or not?

I just found out about Capabilities, as I needed to switch **In-App-Purchases** on.

[image]

Comment: Only if your app is providing routing for other apps (like Google Maps or Apple Maps).

Comment: what do you mean with providing routing? I am just using MapKit to display a map in my app with some annotations

Comment: "providing routing" means giving directions from point A to point B.

Comment: Ah ok, I am not using this. Does it mean, I don't need to switch that capability on?

Comment: Correct. Since you are not providing that service you don't turn that capability on.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You only turn the Maps capability on if your app is meant to provide routing (navigation/direction) services to other apps.

Based on your comments, your app will not be providing this service so you don't need to turn on the Maps capability.